# In R, can I filter a dataframe so that only rows that contain certain substrings are included?

Tags: r, dplyr, shiny, shinydashboard

Say I have a dashboard in R Shiny that allows users to filter on a table about dogs using a multiple-select "dogs filter" as defined in my `ui` section below

```
virtualSelectInput(
      inputId = "select_dog_breed",
      label = "Dog Breed",
      choices = unique(df$`Dog Breed`),
      showValueAsTags = TRUE,
      search = TRUE,
      multiple = TRUE
    ),
```

this filter successfully filters out any rows that don't have one of the selected dog breeds using the logic below in the `server` section of my dashboard:

```
# fdf is my filtered dataframe
if (!is.null(input$select_dog_breed)) {
      fdf = fdf %>%
        filter(`Dog Breed` %in% input$select_dog_breed)
    }
```

my table then successfully updates with the filtered dataframe (`fdf`). Therefore, if the user selected "Golden Retriever" and "Black Labrador" on the filter, only rows where `Dog Breed` equals one of those options are included in their reactive table.

My problem is, how can I create a filter that only includes rows where the `Dog Breed` column contains one of one or more selected substrings? For example, say I only want to include any breeds of Belgian or British origin, how could I create a filter that only returns rows where the `Dog Breed` contains at least one of those strings ("British" or "Belgian")?

I've tried creating a function like the one below

```
contains_substring <- function(dog_breed_column, substrings) {
    for (substring in substrings) {
        if (any(grepl(substring, c(dog_breed_column)))) {
            return (TRUE)
        }
    }
    return (FALSE)
}
```

If I call `contains_substring("belgian mastiff", c("belgian", "british"))`, this function returns TRUE as expected, and if I call `contains_substring("belgian mastiff", c("swiss", "british"))`, it correctly returns FALSE. My question is, how can I implement a function like this in order to filter a table?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [filter a data frame in R language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72441790/filter-a-data-frame-in-r-language)

Comment: @Limey not quite, but thank you! I solved it with this logic here:

`
if (!is.null(input$select_substrings_to_include)) {
      filter_regex_string <- paste(input$select_substrings_to_include, collapse="|")
      fdf = fdf %>%
        filter(str_detect(`Dog Breed`, filter_regex_string))
    }
`